# Can we schedule UNUserNotificationCenter only in specific view controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

I want to show notification only in specific pages like if the userid obtained from payload of notification is not equal to the current userid. Where should I use this condition inside appdelegate? I have used *willPresent* delegate of `userNotificationCenter` to deliver the notification when app is in foreground and requesting permission to show notification method in `didFinishLauchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`.

Sample code of *willPresent* method is given below.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void){

    if let userID = notification.request.content.userInfo["user_id"] {
        self.userIDSelected = userID as! String
    }
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    if self.currentuserID != self.userIDSelected
    {
        completionHandler([.alert,.badge,.sound])
    }
    else
    {
         completionHandler([])
    }
}
```